# Can't drag an outlet in XCode 13

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to create a custom UIView subclass in the XCode 13.4.1, according to [this tutorial](https://betterprogramming.pub/swift-3-creating-a-custom-view-from-a-xib-ecdfe5b3a960).

I have created a custom UIView subclass:

```
// MyView.swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MyView: UIView {

}
```

And I have created a `MyView.xib` and set the `File's Owner` class property to `MyView`.

When I open the assistent editor, it finds `MyView.swift` automatically, but I cannot drag outlets from the `.xib` into my custom class.

What am I missing here to be able to do this?

Comment: Did you also provided your custom class in the .xib?

Comment: Write the IBOutlet code first. Then drag from the left circle of the outlet to the xib.